# How to Check if string contains commas?

Tags: javascript

Fetching an CSV file using ajax request. Now, I want separate CSV's into array of values and render an list of all values.

Comment: what does the csv look like?

Comment: Is this Java or Javascript?  What do you mean by "render"?   And what does this have to do with the question's title.

Comment: @Federico - have you heard the saying "You can't polish a turd"?

Comment: @StephenC I tried and I failed. Next time I'll keep my keyboard still.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) which will turn a string into an array.

```js
let csv = "Chelsea,Liverpool,Man United";
let splitCSV = csv.split(",");
console.log(splitCSV);
```